# UICollectionView selection and delete issue with diffable data sources

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, diffabledatasource

I'm at my wits end here, but I have a weird issue with my collectionview and trying to select multiple items. I have an edit button, that when I hit it it triggers an isEditing function. When a cell is tapped, it changes the bool on isSelected. 
What I'm trying to do, is have multiple cells get selected, and then hit a trash can button to delete the selected items. I'm running into two problems:

1. If I select multiple objects then hit my delete button- then it remove some but not all of the objects.
2. If I hit my edit button and select a couple of objects then hit cancel, then go back into edit mode, some objects are selected again.

My edit code is here:

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = editing
        let indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
        for indexPath in indexPaths {
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
            cell.isInEditingMode = editing
        }

    }
```

and my delete button code is here:

```
if let selectedCells = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
            for indexPath in selectedCells {
                if let items = dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: indexPath) {
                    var snapshot = dataSource.snapshot()
                    container.viewContext.delete(items)
                    saveChangesToDisk()
                    snapshot.deleteItems([items])
                    dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
                }

            }
            isEditing = false
        }
```

My full project is here (linking specifically to my collectionview.swift: https://github.com/analogpotato/superdiff/blob/master/superdiff/CollectionViewController.swift

Comment: It looks like you are applying snapshots all over the place. My first suggestion would be to have all updates flow through a single function.

You should be able to delete the items through CoreData, then generate a new snapshot, append all the remaining items to that snapshot, and then apply the new snapshot.

I'd see if doing that, and removing the `snap.deleteItems()` manipulation you are doing would simplify your flow and allow you to better troubleshoot where things are going wrong.